# God damn if..(sí que (eso) es/si (eso) no es/si es que (eso) es)[Adverbio de afirmación]

Tags: traducción, gramática, uso-de-palabras, adverbios

> I didn't realize that that was something that you could do. Thank you for this comment!

> God damn if that ain't the truth.

¿Cómo traducirías esto?

Es un comentario de aprobación a otro comentario de agradecimiento de la resolución de un problema que no se resolvió de forma convencional.

- (a)..x.. **sí que (eso) es** verdad(Adverbio de afirmación que se usa para responder una pregunta)
- (b)..x.. **si (eso) no es** verdad(Hago algo inusual o perjudicial para mi si eso no llega a ser verdad)
- (c)..x.. **si es que (eso) es** verdad.

Creo que según lo que coloques en ..x.. hará varíe lo siguiente, tomando un valor positivo("es") o negativo("no es") o duda.

El problema es cuando es negativo en relación con la periferia izquierda, pero ¿"Sí que (eso) es..." es una construcción correcta?

Comment: Yo lo leo cómo "...x... si no fuese verdad". Pero mi inglés es un poco barriobajero ;-) y tampoco me complico demasiado, voy a lo inmediato.

Comment: I think the exclamation _God damn if that ain't the truth_ is informal and possibly US dialect. I would be surprised to hear it in the UK.

Answer (score 1):

No estime que podrías hacerlo. ¡Gracias por este comentario!

Caramba, (coloquial) es cierto! ("si es verdad!", "eso" se sobrentiende, "sí, si "eso" es verdad"). Estoy de acuerdo (normalmente con tono derrotado, malhumorado o pesimista).

---

- "if  isn't old Bluddnok!  - ¡Qué sorpresa ver al amigo Bludnock! (Form.)
- "if  isn't old Bluddnok! - ¡Si es el viejo Bludnock! (Lit.)